# Strange MathJax line break behavior in mobile browsers

Tags: bug, mathjax

I originally posted this on Puzzling SE Meta [[link]](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2869) (which I should probably close now), but decided to move it here on Stack Exchange Meta because I found this bug occurring on other SE sites.

I was looking at [one of my answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10550/10248) on my mobile browser (Safari for iPhone 4S iOS 7.1.2, but the result is the same on any mobile browser I've tried so far), and I found a broken MathJax snippet: the mathematical expression is mixed with the text of the answer making it hard to understand its meaning.

**This happens probably because of the snippet being larger than the answer's container: the MathJax expression wraps, but the answer's text doesn't, and this causes an odd result.**

I'm adding a screenshot from my iPhone:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Heh. You're not the only one who ran into creepy crappy MathJax. Thanks for pointing out though. I would've left this issue "undiscussed".

Comment: @MARamezani in my opinion this matter is not getting enough attention, perhaps some upvotes here on meta may help to solve the issue (or at least I hope so).

Comment: Somewhat similar bug report on [math.meta.se]: [Period in a wrong position when Mathjax is viewed on iPhone](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31167).