# MathJax not rendering properly in comment on mobile-sized screen

Tags: bug, comments, mathjax, responsive-design

MathJax is not rendering properly in the comment of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480833/using-complex-number-in-integration) post.

Original comment:
[image]

In mobile view:
[image]

Comment: It's almost like it's cut in parts and then glued together again wrongly. The formulae themselves are still rendered but the overflow of the formula and the sentence don't agree with each other.

Comment: This happens everywhere, including in posts and in the profile page.

Comment: Related, but unanswered: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253036/334566

Comment: What The Amplitwist said. It's just more noticeable in comments. Reloading the page in landscape mode often helps. As a workaround,  you can use display mode (double dollars) to prevent plain text and MathJax from being incorrectly mixed together.

Comment: And no one has bothered to fix it?!

Comment: @Shub It's not exactly an easy thing to fix. MathJax changes the rendered oart to an inline-block. When there isn't enough space to render it fully on one line, it breaks it onto new lines. But since it's contained within an inline block, that allows other text to continue wrapping if it's shorter than what it wanted to put there, making this really odd situation. I doubt there even is a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Question titles with MathJax formula may cause issues too on mobile: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378009/178179